# issues building ruby native extension

Tags: ruby, ruby-native-extensions

I've created some code in c that I'd like to call from ruby. I've used [this article](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2010/12/11/writing-ruby-c-extensions-part-2.html) as a guide, but I'm having problems getting it to run without linking issues.

To start, I have to directly copy the source files into my `ext/NAME/` directory. They don't seem to be picked up if I git submodule them into that directory, meaning they'd be under some subdirectory like `ext/NAME/CLIB_GIT_SUBMODULE_FILES/`.

Next, it seems like I have to run my c projects makefile, otherwise I run into segfaults. If I run my makefile, object files (`.o`) are created in the `ext/NAME` directory, and now when I try to run rake (which runs my test cases under `/test/` I see linking issues like:

```
linking shared-object NAME/NAME.so
gcc: error: SOMEFILE_ONE.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: SOMEFILE_TWO.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: SOMEFILE_THREE.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [ruby_fast_numerizer.so] Error 1
rake aborted!
```

Note that when I run the makefile under `ext/NAME/` it creates `SOMEFILE_ONE.o`, etc.

I'm not sure what's going on at this point :( The guides all seem to be writing new c code in the `ext/NAME` directory, not wrapping an existing c library. I tried looking at other projects for guidance like [nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri), but they're doing a whole lot more which makes it hard to sift through.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Building an extension

Normally, `ext/NAME/extconf.rb` uses `mkmf` (MakeMakefile) to write a new Makefile with all the configuration to build a Ruby extension from the provided sources. MakeMakefile has defaults for where to find source code, headers, and all the other pieces, but you can override them (using `dir_config` for example).

The generated Makefile will have instructions to compile source files and link everything with the relevant Ruby libraries to produce a native Ruby extension.

If you have an existing C library which has nothing to do with Ruby, it probably has its own Makefile and build process. Don't confuse Ruby's generated Makefile with your own!

### Loading a library

For wrapping an existing C library, I would not build a native extension at all, but instead load the library with FFI. The two major FFI options are Fiddle (comes with Ruby, but tutorials are scarce) or the `ffi` gem (better documented, but requires a gem).

### Additional resources

- RubyGems has an official guide for [gems with extensions](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/)
- Ruby itself comes with a [guide to extensions](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/extension_rdoc.html#label-Prepare+extconf.rb)

Comment: I'll take a look at FFI and let you know if that resolves my problem!

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if this is what I need. I'd like to eventually turn this into a gem and FFI will simplify the interface part but doesn't handle building the c library as well, unless it does and I'm missing that?

Comment: You got it right, FFI helps with *loading* and *calling* an already-installed C library (one that has nothing to do with Ruby). For comparison, consider the Nokogiri gem: the nokogiri extension doesn't *build* `libxml2` -- you have to have it installed already. The nokogiri extension does do some compilation, but only for the stuff specific to the Ruby extension.

Comment: What does "you can override them using dir_config" mean?